# How can I parse image from table cell inside table view to detail view in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have an image inside my tableview cell. 
What I want to do is when I click on that cell I want to parse both text & image to detail view.
I can do for text but I can't get the point about image.
So, simply my question is how can I parse image inside tableview cell to detail view in iOS.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using another viewController to show the detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it as the same way you're using it. Use indexPath to specify the row you wanna manipulate.

Here's how you do it. implement `UITableViewDelegate` in your ViewController, and implement the following method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, you access the image the same way that you set it.  In the case of the standard `UITableViewCell`, it is the `imageView` property that you used.

For these API type questions though, there is no better place to start, than the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW34)